# Can browse, but can't ping

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-7, firewall, git, ping

I am behind a corporate network. I am unable to use git, since it can't resolve server names

```
fatal: Unable to look up someserver.org (port 9418) (No such host is known. )
```

I can't ping that server (name nor ip) either, but my browser is resolving it just fine.

Is there a way to figure out a workaround for this?

Comment: Put the IP address resolved by the browser in your local hosts file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES,

Usually corporate networks are behind proxy.
Try to find your git repo server public IP (google it), ping it. If it isn't working you are probably behind a proxy server. If you are behind proxy use:

git config --global http.proxy http://proxy_address:proxy_port

git clone http://.../..

You can find proxy address in internet explorer properties\Connections\LAN Settings

[image]

If git has still problem resolving address you could try putting git repo public IP DNS to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file. Git will resolve DNS locally and use proxy for connection.

**Here are some additional methods how you can discover proxy:**

1. Open IE, browse to some page next run from cmd:

netstat -ban

(it requires elevated command prompt - probably you can't do it on the corporate computer)

on the left sight under [IEXPLORER.EXE] is your IP on the right sight should be proxy IP and port.

[image]

2. run:

ipconfig /all - find your DNS suffix

ping wpad.suffix or ping wpad

Now use the IP address returned by the ping command and us it in your browser:

http://ipaddress/wpad.dat

It will download wpad.dat file in which you can find line "PROXY ..." containing IP and port of your proxy.

Comment: Only general tab is visible in my case, cannot figure out if proxy is in use. I can't ping ip addresses either.

Comment: Company policy to hide settings using GPO on windows probably. I will look in it. Are you able to install software on your corporate computer ?

Comment: OK so you have some options to investigate proxy setup:

Comment: I think I've managed to get a proxy server address via netstat. I can access webpages via a command line with curl --proxy. But git still fails with "Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT". I guess it is another question now, was unable to find a working solution online.

Comment: This answer helped me http://stackoverflow.com/a/25993353/187752. I had to *unset* the http.proxy and https.proxy variables in global config.

Answer (score 1):

I often use an external, browser based, dns/ip lookup tool, like [GetIP](http://www.getip.com), to get the ip address of a server I'm trying to connect to.  Then you can use the address for git, svn, etc as long as it's not explicitly blocked by your corporate firewall or proxy.

Comment: I can reach the address via browser, but can't ping neither name nor ip.